# Inequality $\frac{a^3}{bc} + \frac{b^3}{ac} + \frac{c^3}{ab} + \frac{1}{abc} \ge min$ with $a+b+c = \frac{3}{2}$

Tags: inequality, optimization, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

For arbitrary positive reals $a, b, c$, such that $a+b+c = \frac{3}{2}$, I want to find

$$\min(\frac{a^3}{bc} + \frac{b^3}{ac} + \frac{c^3}{ab} + \frac{1}{abc})$$

$\frac{a^3}{bc} + \frac{b^3}{ac} \ge 2 \sqrt{\frac{(ab)^3}{abc^2}} = 2 \frac{ab}{c}$, and similarly for two other pairs, so

$\frac{a^3}{bc} + \frac{b^3}{ac} + \frac{c^3}{ab} + \frac{1}{abc} \ge \frac{ab}{c} + \frac{ac}{b} + \frac{bc}{a} + \frac{1}{abc} \ge \frac{(ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ac)^2+ 1}{abc} \ge \frac{4\sqrt[4]{(abc)^4}}{abc} = 4$

But Lagrange multipliers giving the minimum of $\frac {19} {2}$ (and also the fact that the problem can't be so trivial) suggest that there is no use trying to find a tripple that results in $\frac{a^3}{bc} + \frac{b^3}{ac} + \frac{c^3}{ab} + \frac{1}{abc} = 4$, so another approach is needed.

It may boil down to simply using CS once and I just can't see it.

Comment: Are you perhaps investigating this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4745280/if-3-numbers-of-the-form-frac1q21-have-a-mean-of-frac12-will-on)? If not, it looks it could be related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a=b=c=\frac{1}{2}$ we obtain a value $9.5$.

We'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Indeed, after homogenization we need to prove that:
$$\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{abc\cdot\frac{a+b+c}{\frac{3}{2}}}+\frac{\left(\frac{a+b+c}{\frac{3}{2}}\right)^3}{abc}\geq\frac{19}{2}$$ or
$$\frac{3(a^4+b^4+c^4)}{abc(a+b+c)}+\frac{16(a+b+c)^3}{27abc}\geq19,$$ which is true by Muirhead and AM-GM (in fact, the first one also easily follows from AM-GM):
$$a^4+b^4+c^4\geq abc(a+b+c)$$ and $$(a+b+c)^3\geq27abc.$$

Comment: Thanks. But I have a few questions. 1) Did you just guess the minimum is likely to be when all vars are equal? I even made a mistake in my question giving the wrong number, yet you still were sure that min is $9.5$.

Comment: 2) How did you homodemize the LHS so quickly?

Comment: @Sgg8 Yes, I took $a=b=c$ and it turned out. I am ready to explain, how I got a homogenization. Explain?

Comment: I see how the condition on the sum was utilised to add or subtract the degree wherever needed. I'm rather wondering how did you see so quickly that homogenization is the way to kill it

Comment: @Sgg8 I added something. See now.

Comment: I noticed how you homogenized it. What I didn't see right away was that homogenization would help

Comment: @Sgg8 Yes, homogenization it's very useful.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the thought process you used. Did you somehow have $a^4+b^4+c^4 \ge abc(a+b+c)$ "on top of all the inequalities stored your head" and as soon as you saw the problem you noticed that it would be useful? Or have you simply tried homogenizing "just to see what happens" and it worked out?

Comment: @Sgg8 I saw that it will help. Just I solved during my life one or maybe two problems. I have a bit of experience

Comment: I'm not as good as you at inequalities, but I figure the lower bound on the number of inequalities you've proven can be made much tighter than that

Comment: @Sgg8 No. I proved that $9.5$ is a minimal value.

Comment: Read my comment again:)

Comment: @Sgg8 :  "but I figure the lower bound on the number of inequalities you've proven can be made much tighter than that" The lower bound it's 9.5. I proved it.

Comment: I'll rephrase. You said you solved one or two problems. I think it is much more than that

Comment: Or maybe I'm mistaken and you indeed have a proof that you solved 9.5 problems

Comment: @Sgg8 Now, I understood :)

Answer (score 1):

So we need to find maximal $k$ such that $$a^4+b^4+c^4 +1\geq kabc$$ for all positive $a,b,c$ with $a+b+c  =3/2$. Puting $a=b=c =1/2$ we get $19/16\geq k/8$ so $k\leq 19/2$.

Let's check if $k_{\max} = 19/2$? Using Cauchy inequality twice and Am-Gm in the third line we get.

\begin{align}a^4+b^4+c^4 &\geq {1\over 3}(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2\\ &\geq {1\over 9}(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b+c)^2 \\
& \geq \sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}\sqrt[3]{abc}(a+b+c)\\&=3abc/2\end{align}

So we are left to check if $$3abc/2 +1\geq 19abc/2  $$ is true i.e. if $8abc\leq 1$ is true. But this is true by AM-GM since $a+b+c =3/2$.

Comment: Also, by AM-GM  $a^4+b^4+c^4\geq a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2\geq abc(a+b+c),$ but Muirhead gives a result immediately.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Yeah, also nice.

Comment: Wow! Very beautiful and straightforward!

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=e^p$, $b=e^q$ and $c=e^r$ for $p,q,r\in \mathbb{R}$. Then the expression becomes

$$f(p,q,r)=e^{3p-q-r}+e^{3q-p-r}+e^{3r-p-q}+e^{-p-q-r}$$

for $a+b+c=\frac{3}{2}$. Suppose (WLOG) $p\ge q\ge r$ and $p>r$. Then for small enough $\epsilon >0$, it is easy to show the inequality below by Karamata's Majorization Inequality:

$$f(p,q,r) \ge f(p-\epsilon,q,r+\epsilon)$$

Hence, the minimum value of the expression is held when $p=q=r$, $a=b=c$, and the expression equals to $\frac{19}{2}$ .

Comment: Do you have to check if $f$ is convex?

Comment: @nonuser it is enough to check if $e^x$ is convex

Comment: Why?.........................